# batch forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series, batch-processing, forecasting

I am trying to write an R script to forecast many time series automatically by using the library(forecast) by Prof. Hyndman.
Following his suggestion I am using a general code structure like this:

```
library(forecast)

retail <- read.csv("http://robjhyndman.com/data/ausretail.csv",header=FALSE)
retail <- ts(retail[,-1],f=12,s=1982+3/12)

ns <- ncol(retail)
h <- 24
fcast <- matrix(NA,nrow=h,ncol=ns)
for(i in 1:ns)
  fcast[,i] <- forecast(retail[,i],h=h)$mean

write(t(fcast),file="retailfcasts.csv",sep=",",ncol=ncol(fcast))
```

I would like to make thing a little bit more complicated by estimating more models for each series and then to automatically get the model with the minimum MAPE on a test set. In other words, I would like to estimate ARIMA, ARIMA with regressor and Ets, compare their performance on the tests set and then produce the forecast with the best model. 
Would you be so kind to suggest me how to set up the code? I need in particular to compare the ARIMA with the ARIMAX model.

Thank you very much for your help

Best Regards

Comment: The forecast package automatically compares models and produces the best. Otherwise, you have to define the `model =`  in the forecast function OR use forecast.Arima(), forecast.ets().  I feel like all the forecast options are well described in the documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf

Comment: Thank you Ryan. If I am not wrong using forecast.Arima(), forecast.ets() and so on, I get the best Arima (or the best Arima with xreg) and the best ets model; what I need is to  compare these 'best performers' and get the best among them. Always in the most automatic way. Thank you